# Ansible equivalent to echo "foo" > bar.txt

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there an Echo equivalent to `echo "foo" > bar.txt`?

Which, instead of the Ansible `lineinfile` module, makes sure ONLY this one line is in the file, even if something was in the file before. This should then be overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module with `content`:

```
- copy: content=foo dest=bar.txt
```

Comment: So I have to use a template if the content depends on a Ansible parameter?

Comment: You can replace `content=foo` with `content="{{foo_var}}"` as usual in Ansible